# How to use values multiple TextBoxes and store them in a RichTextBox and a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

Hello i want to make multi value result from textboxt into Richtextbox and listbox, sorry for my bad english, but see image below:

[my form][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Xys.png

question:
i want to make this form is functional
thank you before

Edit 1:
i already search at google and found this code for used **Textbox to listbox**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text) End Sub
```

and result in the listbox is only **Name1** not all input textbox (**Addr 1 and Phone 1**)

I want to if:

- Name = Name 1
- Phone = Phone 1
- Address = Addr 1

Then results is:
Rich textbox:

> Name 1, Phone 1 Addr 1

Then in the Listbox result is

**Name 1** is for Title and represents from all **Name, Phone and Address** data

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Please read [ask] very carefully.  Perhaps visit the [help].  This is a QA site, not a code factory. `i want to make this form is functional` is **not** a question.  You need to do your own research and show some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: for result listbox i use this `Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub`

Comment: `i want to make this form is functional.`, not bad english per say, but what do you mean by functional?

Comment: @Codexer see my edit at first topic, i need help with listbox code, and delete button code

Comment: Please don't edit the word SOLVED into question titles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have done some more research as what you want to do is very simple (If i understood you question correctly) and im sure you would have solved your problem, but here is the code you need:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each ln As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ln.Split(",")(0))
    Next
End Sub
```